# exists r > 0 such that ∇2f (x) > 0 for any x ∈ B(x0,r).

Tags: optimization

Let f : U ⊆ Rn → R be a twice continuously differentiable function. Let x0 be an interior point of U such that ∇^2f(x0)> 0(hessian). Prove that there exists r > 0 such that ∇2f (x) > 0 for any x ∈ B(x0,r).

i tried to prove it with minor criteria
.

Answer (score 0):

For any continuous function $g$ on a  topological space $\{x: g(x) >0\}$ is open. When the domain is  a metric space $g(x_0) >0$ implies $B(x_0,r) \subset \{x: g(x) >0\}$ for  some $r>0$.